# Aligning columns inside a stack - flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I'm trying to align a colum in the middle of the screen in flutter using this code but it sits on the top of the screen , I want to place the image and the spinner in the center of the screen and a text at the bottom :

```
@override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Scaffold(
  backgroundColor: Color(0xFFF9F8FD),
  body: Stack(
    children: [
      Align(
        alignment: Alignment.center,
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Image.asset(
              'assets/test.png',
              height: 100,
              width: 100,
            ),
            SpinKitThreeBounce(
              color: Color(0xFF0C9869),
              size: 30.0,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      Align(
        alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
        child: RichText(
          text: TextSpan(
            text: 'A project by : ',
            style: TextStyle(
              height: 1,
              fontSize: 20,
              fontStyle: FontStyle.italic,
              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
              color: Color(0xFF0C9869),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ],
  ),
);
}
 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Control the Column alignment by using

```
Column(
    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
```

You can also control how much a widget takes of the screen by using:

```
Container(
 height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.9, 
//This will give the widget 90%. You can change the percentage.
```

There are other ways to do this, but this is the simplest one. Here's your code.

```
return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Color(0xFFF9F8FD),
      body: Container(
        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Container(
              height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height *
                  0.9, //This will give the widget 90% of the screen height,
              child: Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                children: [
                  Image.asset(
                    'assets/test.png',
                    height: 100,
                    width: 100,
                  ),
                  CircularProgressIndicator(),
                ],
              ),
            ),

            // SpinKitThreeBounce(
            //   color: Color(0xFF0C9869),
            //   size: 30.0,
            // ),
            RichText(
              text: TextSpan(
                text: 'A project by : ',
                style: TextStyle(
                  height: 1,
                  fontSize: 20,
                  fontStyle: FontStyle.italic,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                  color: Color(0xFF0C9869),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

You can using column with your `stack` and `sizedbox` that create the top height

```
body: Column(
children:[
SizedBox(
            height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height*0.35,
          ),
          Stack(
            children: [
              Align(
                alignment: Alignment.center,
                child: Column(
                  children: [
                    Image.asset(
                      'assets/test.png',
                      height: 100,
                      width: 100,
                    ),
                    SpinKitThreeBounce(
                      color: Color(0xFF0C9869),
                      size: 30.0,
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
              Align(
                alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                child: RichText(
                  text: TextSpan(
                    text: 'A project by : ',
                    style: TextStyle(
                      height: 1,
                      fontSize: 20,
                      fontStyle: FontStyle.italic,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                      color: Color(0xFF0C9869),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
]
)
```